# How can I tell when data has started to arrive from my URL request?

Tags: ios, networking

Using either NSURLConnection or NSURLSession, how can I tell when data has started to arrive? My download may be large or my connection slow so I want to make an update to the UI once data starts to arrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUrlSession` has a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate/1411528-urlsession?language=ft) that should help you, if you're interested in knowing the each block of data is received.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, 
              didReceive data: Data)
```

And this [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession) if just the headers received is useful.

```
optional func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, 
              didReceive response: URLResponse, 
       completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void)
```

Comment: Is that called multiple times as data arrives or is that the entire data download?

Comment: Multiple times. But I have updated the answer based on your response @AaronBratcher